# Chrome cookies not working after tomcat web server reboot

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, cookies

I noticed recently, that when I reboot my Tomcat web server, that the Chrome browser can no longer store cookies.  i.e. tomcat uses cookies for http sessions, and the browser can no longer get its http session, also the cookie we use to store the logged in user fails, and the user does not remain logged in.

This seems to be a new issue with Chrome, perhaps from a recent update, I do not remember seeing it before. If I close the Chrome browser, then reopen it, it is fine again (until the server is rebooted again).

The issue does not happen on Firefox, seems like a bug in Chrome.

Has anyone else noticed this issue, or know of a solution?

I found some posts about Chrome/tomcat cookie issues and the suggestion to set,
sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash=false in the context.xml
but this does not fix the issue.

It seems it might be related to the website supporting both https and http, and switching between the two (although it did occur on a website that did not support https as well...)

Okay, I can now recreate the issue, steps are.

1. connect to website via https
2. logout / login
3. connect to website via http
4. Tomcat JSESSIONID cookie can no longer be stored (oddly user/password cookies are stored)

This only happens on Chrome, and only since the Chrome update that add the "insecure" flag on login pages that use http

Okay I added this to my web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

This did not fix the issue, but made the issue always occur through http, i.e. make http no longer able to store the JSESSIONID cookie.
I tried `<secure>false</secure>` but still get the old issue.
So, it is related to this setting at least. Anyone have any ideas?

Logged bug on Chrome,
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=698741

Comment: So it seems to happen on the new version of Chrome in the Chrome browser is open too long, it suddenly cannot keep the cookies for the website, the JSESSIONID is suddenly never set. The same website using no 'www' works when the www version starts to fail, https also seems to work, very odd.

Comment: My guess is this is a bug in a recent chrome update, that seems to have been since fixed. But if someone has not restarted chrome, they still have the bug version that cannot store cookies correctly in some states.

Comment: This issue still occurs in Chrome, somehow if you leave it running too long, it starts to not keep cookies for some websites

Comment: This does not answer your question, thus it is just a comment: Try to write a Selenium integration test reproducing the issue. Once it is automated, you can play with variations, maybe find workarounds, report the bug etc. Reproduceable bugs are usually fixed much quicker.

Comment: I cannot consistently reproduce it.  Once the browser stops saving cookies, then it is consistent in not working, but once I restart chrome it is fine again. The issue has occurred on several of our Tomcat websites, and from several different machines, always from Chrome only, and always ok after a restart. Only in the last month or so after the last Chrome update that added to "insecure" flag on any login page not using https

Comment: It seems to only occur on the http version of our websites, not using https, but not certain on that.

Comment: Another odd thing, when the issue occurs, the Tomcat JSESSIONID cookie is no longer stored, but our own cookies for user/token are still able to be stored.

Comment: Aha, here it gets interesting. So it seems to be (or could be) connected to secure cookies. The easiest way around this would be to no longer offer HTTP but only HTTPS, using secure cookies. Are you aware of the problem that a secure cookie received via HTTPS can be overwritten (and possibly abused) by an HTTP response? See [here](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/cookies-secure-flag-undesired-behavior-modern-browsers/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540089/why-do-browsers-accept-secure-cookies-sent-over-a-non-secure-http-connection). Maybe your problem is related to that.

Comment: And maybe - pure speculation - Chrome's new version tries to stop this from happening, somehow resulting in your usual way of using/testing the web site, maybe even switching back and forth between HTTP and HTTPS from the same browser session, exhibits the symptoms described in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this might be the issue.  I tried switching between http and https (it was ok), then logging in/out/in on each and it recreated the error.  But I think the error has occurred without switching before, and occurred on our one website that does not support https, so no certain this is the issue.  If it is the issue, any idea how to avoid it other than not allow http anymore?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. As I said, I was speculating, making an educated guess. If I knew the answer for sure, I would write one and snatch the bounty. ;-)

Answer (score 13):

I was able to reproduce your problem with Chrome: Just it is needed to create `HttpSession` from HTTPS zone. Any subsequent HTTP request will not send the session cookie and any attempt to `Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=` through HTTP is ignored by chrome.

The problem is localized when the user switch from HTTPS to HTTP. The HTTPS session cookie is maintained even if server is restarted and is working properly. (I tested with Tomcat6, Tomcat 9, and using an apache proxy for SSL)

This is response header sent by Tomcat when session is created from HTTPS

```
 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=CD93A1038E89DFD39F420CE0DD460C72;path=/cookietest;Secure;HttpOnly
```

and this one for HTTP (note `Secure` is missing)

```
 Set-Cookie:SESSIONID=F909DBEEA37960ECDEA9829D336FD239;path=/cookietest;HttpOnly
```

Chrome ignores the second `set-Cookie`. On the other hand Firefox and Edge replace the `Secure` cookie with the not-`secured`. To determine what the correct behaviour should be I have reviewed [RFC2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt)

> **4.3.3  Cookie Management**
>
> If a user agent receives a Set-Cookie response header whose NAME is
>      the same as a pre-existing cookie, and whose Domain and Path
>      attribute values exactly (string) match those of a pre-existing
>      cookie, the new cookie supersedes the old.

So, It is clear is a chrome bug, as you supposed in the question: The HTTP cookie should replace the one setted by HTTPS

Removing cookie manually from Chrome or invalidating the session at server side makes it work again (if after these actions the session is created using HTTP)

By default the JSESSIONID cookie is created with `Secure` when is requested from HTTPS. I guess this is the reason that Chrome do not allow to overwrite the cookie. But if you try to set `<secure>false</secure>` in `web.xml` Tomcat ignores it and the `Set-Cookie` header is sent with `Secure`

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Changing cookie name, setting `sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash` or removing `HttpOnly` has had no effect

I could not find a workaround for this issue except invalidating server session when logged user switch from HTTPS to HTTP.

Finally I opened a bug in chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=698839

---

**UPDATED**
The issue is finally marked as **Won't Fix** because it is an intentional change. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4506322921848832

> **Strict Secure Cookies**
>
> This adds restrictions on cookies marked with the 'Secure' attribute. Currently, Secure cookies cannot be accessed by insecure (e.g. HTTP) origins. However, insecure origins can still add Secure cookies, delete them, or indirectly evict them. This feature modifies the cookie jar so that insecure origins cannot in any way touch Secure cookies. This does leave a carve out for cookie eviction, which still may cause the deletion of Secure cookies, but only after all non-Secure cookies are evicted.

Comment: As I read this excellent comment I also thought that this should be reported as a bug in Chromium. To the question OP, here's the issue tracker URL: https://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/

Comment: @i336_ I reviewed the RFC and I think it is definitively a bug. In the updated answer is the link. May be some stars could help...

Comment: I just opened that issue (698839) to discover it has been WontFix'ed. :( FYI, closed tickets don't generate updates; don't bother updating that one if you have any arguments for why it was closed or want to revise it. Just make a new one and edit the question here with the new issue URL. (Speaking from experience)

Comment: Also, if you have the spare resources, you could edit the question with an obfuscated link (triple base64, or a Python oneliner, etc) to an isolated minimal live testcase that demonstrates this issue (with no ability to edit the code - just test login/logout). Then people could poke at that live instance for themselves. Just a thought, not necessary; might be an idea if you want an answer super quick (considering the bounty).

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing this a couple of times and as far as I can remember this was the only recommendation on the matter, as you mentioned:

A possible solution to this might be adding `sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash=false` in the `context.xml` and see how that goes.

Some info on the matter from [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)

[image]

A discussion [here (same solution)](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1216367/1216366)

Hope I didn't confuse the issues and this helps you, let me know with a comment if I need to edit/if worked/if I should delete, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [draft document](http://httpwg.org/http-extensions/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-alone.html) to deprecate the modification of 'secure' cookies from non-secure origins (submitted by Google). It specifies the recommendations to amend the [HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) document.

Abstract of the document:

> This document updates RFC6265 by removing the ability for a non-
> secure origin to set cookies with a 'secure' flag, and to overwrite
> cookies whose 'secure' flag is set.  This deprecation improves the
> isolation between HTTP and HTTPS origins, and reduces the risk of
> malicious interference.

Chrome [already implemented this feature in v 52](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4506322921848832) and same feature is also [implemented in Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=976073) few days back.

To solve this issue, I think you should connect to website via https only.

Answer (score 0):

The bad way I think is to set `sessionCookieName = "JSESSIONIDForHttp"` in `context.xml`

Let Browser's cookie know:

1. If secure `https` condition use default `"JSESSIONID"`.
2. If not secure `http` condition use `"JSESSIONIDForHttp"`.